# Shift focus from one JTree node to another

Tags: java, xml, swing, jtree, mouselistener

I need to shift focus from a JTree node to another node on the previous node being clicked.

Example XML document:

```
<br/>
<'obo'><br/>
<'term'><br/>
<'id'>GO:0001<'/id'><br/>
<'name'>candida... '<'/name'><br/>
<'dbname'>' blah blah '<'/dbname'><br/>
<'is_a'>'GO:0035'<'/is_a'><br/>
<'/term'><br/>
<'term'><br/>
<'id'>'GO:0035'<'/id'><br/>
<'name'>'candida... '<'/name'><br/>
<'dbname'>' blah blah '<'/dbname'><br/>
<'is_a'>'GO:00465'<'/is_a'><br/>
<'/term'><br/>
<'/obo'><br/>
```

I have made this into a JTree. Now I need to shift focus to GO:0035 when the user clicks on GO:0001.

I was trying to addTreeSelectionListener() but it doesn't not work in my Eclipse. I thought I could set a loop read each  check if there is a corresponding , if there is a corresponding  then get it's path, add a mouseListener to G0:0001 and setPath to GO:0035.
I'm new to Java so I'm not particularly sure how to do this. Please help out!! :(

Comment: I was trying to addTreeSelectionListener() but it doesn't not work in my Eclipse. I thought I could set a loop read each id tag check if there is a corresponding is_a tag, if there is a corresponding is_a tag then get it's path, add a mouseListener to G0:0001 and setPath to GO:0035. I'm new to Java so I'm not particularly sure how to do this. Please help out!! :(

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear how you are constructing your [`JTree`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html) or [`TreeModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html), but you can find [examples](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#eg) in [*How to Use Trees*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#data). If you use the [`DefaultTreeModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html), you can search from the node returned by the model's [`getRoot()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#getRoot%28%29) method, and you can construct a [`TreePath`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreePath.html) to that destination node. Use the tree's [`setSelectionPath()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#setSelectionPath%28javax.swing.tree.TreePath%29) method to select the node found.

If you still have trouble, edit your question to provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your usage.